# Error:The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first

Tags: android, view

I am using this https://github.com/ISchwarz23/SortableTableView library to show data in custom TableView. What i did is that i passed custom View from xml to UserTableDataAdapter class but i get this error in stacktrace, when Fragment starts:

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

Here is my code:

**Fragment** class:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    DataBaseHelper helper = new DataBaseHelper(getActivity());
    allUsers = helper.getAllUsers();

    v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_add_user, container, false);
    addEditIcons = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_edit_icons, container, false); // CUSTOM VIEW THAT I PASS TO UserTableDataAdapter

    TableView tableView = (TableView<String[]>) v.findViewById(R.id.tableView);
    tableView.setColumnCount(2);
    tableView.setDataAdapter(new UserTableDataAdapter(getActivity(), allUsers, addEditIcons)); // HERE I PASS VIEW 
    SimpleTableHeaderAdapter simpleHeader = new SimpleTableHeaderAdapter(getActivity(), TABLE_HEADERS);
    simpleHeader.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    simpleHeader.setPaddingTop(8);
    simpleHeader.setPaddingBottom(8);

    tableView.setHeaderAdapter(simpleHeader);
    tableView.setHeaderElevation(10);
    int colorEvenRows = getResources().getColor(R.color.white);
    int colorOddRows = getResources().getColor(R.color.et_grey);
    tableView.setDataRowBackgroundProvider(TableDataRowBackgroundProviders.alternatingRowColors(colorEvenRows, colorOddRows));
    tableView.addDataClickListener(new UserClickListener());       
    return  v;
}
```

**UserTableDataAdapter** class:

```
class UserTableDataAdapter extends TableDataAdapter<User> {
View v;

public UserTableDataAdapter(Context context, List<User> data, View v) { // HERE I INITIALIZE CUSTOM VIEW
    super(context, data);
    this.v = v;
}

@Override
public View getCellView(int rowIndex, int columnIndex, ViewGroup parentView) {
    User user = getRowData(rowIndex);
    View renderedView = null;
    switch (columnIndex) {
        case 0:
            renderedView = showLayout(user);
            break;
    }
    return renderedView;
}

private View showLayout (final User user) {
    LinearLayout iconsLayout = v.findViewById(R.id.iconsLayout);
    TextView tvRow = v.findViewById(R.id.tvRow);
    tvRow.setText(user.getSurname().toString());
    return v;
}
```

Comment: The error message clearly tells you what to do.

Comment: Can you tell me if you know please sir?

Comment: Show the line where the error originates?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the library but I all `getView()` style methods should return a new view, so you probably need to change your method to look something like that.

```
private View showLayout (final User user) {
    LinearLayout iconsLayout = v.findViewById(R.id.iconsLayout);
    TextView tvRow = v.findViewById(R.id.tvRow);
    tvRow.setText(user.getSurname().toString());
    return iconsLayout ;
}
```

Also this might not be relevant, but you need to make sure all paths of your `getCellView()` returns a non null view.